# How to distribute your own data on Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, crm, salesforce-service-cloud

I will work on a new project related to salesforce. Actually what we want to do is to have a salesforce API that contains our database and this API will accept connections from our clients. Once we establish the connection the user will have the access to our database too. Since I dont know anything about salesforce right now, I just wanted to ask you if you have some ideas on how to do that ? Is there any existing API doing that ? or We need to implement our new API for salesforce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provides several APIs out of the box that can be used to access the data stored in your Organization.

Have a look at the REST API, Enterprise API and the Partner API. See [Which API Should I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm).

If none of those suit your needs you can use Apex to create your own REST or SOAP based services.